# Where do I get the DB field to base a Crystal formula on?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a tale and built a Crystal straight table report using it via the wizard. The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [report].[WeekdayPivot](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WeekDayId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [T06h00] [int] NOT NULL,
    [T07h00] [int] NOT NULL,
    [T08h00] [int] NOT NULL,
```

So the wizard places `WeekDayId` as the second column. I wish to create a formula that converts thet to `WeeekDayName`, but all I can find is the "Formula" workshop, which doesn't have the usual list of DB fields etc. This is not the right screen, which is very similar, but has a list of DB fields at the top of the right hand tree. How do I find *that* dialogue?

Answer (score 0):

The dialouges you are looking for may have undocked search for those in the second row from the top and once you find click on them you will be able to see the functions and fields